# How to add Horizontal scrollbar in one of the column in QTableView in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qt4.8

I have a `QTableView` with 3 columns. The columns are `Name`,`Type`,`Show`. I want to add `Horizontal Scrollbar`in `Name` column as names in that column are lengthy.

```
How to add Horizontal scrollbar in one of the column in QTableView?
```

Here is my code :

```
void myView :: CreateTable()
{
    myTable = new QTableView();
    myTable ->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    myTable ->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);

    mymodel = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    mymodel ->setColumnCount(3);
    mymodel ->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));
    mymodel ->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Type"));
    mymodel ->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Show"));
}
```

Comment: I do not think this can be done easily, `QTableView` does not have this feature, AFAIK. Certainly it can be done, but it will be a lot of code and hacking.

Comment: That should be possible by implementing your own delegates (for the first column), .ex. using a `QScrollArea` and (if you want synchronised scrolling of the cells) a single `QScrollBar`. Some useful references: [QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForColumn](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn), [QStyledItemDelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#subclassing-qstyleditemdelegate)

Comment: @m7913d Well, the question is whether the scrolling should be done per-cell basis or for the whole column (i.e. scroll all cells in the column at the same time). And if per-cell then the question is whether the cell must be activated before scrolling - as a user I would probably like to be able to scroll (with touchpad or mouse wheel) the cells upon which I am hovering cursor... And I do not think this is easy to implement with delegates. Of course, the exact requirements should be defined by OP, there are still many details unknown what he wants to achieve.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile  If currently there are 4 entries in a table and let's say 3rd row , Name column has long name, then ONLY 3rd row's Name column should have Horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile ,m7913d   From your comments, it seems that, it is difficult for me as I am new to Qt. So I am thinking alternative to this. And I thought about text elision.  But still I am not able to see the whole string.  If you have any better idea's, please share.

Comment: @tushar I am using text elision plus full length text in tool tip.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile  I tried this code for text elision.  `QString elidedText = tableView->fontMetrics().elidedText(name,Qt::ElideRight, tableView->columnWidth(0));`

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile  Above code worked but I want `Qt::ElideLeft`. And for that it is not working.  Why ?  How should be the code for `Qt::ElideLeft`  ?

Comment: Use `QTableView::setTextElideMode()` see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#textElideMode-prop

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile I tried this code also `tableView->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideNone);`  But not showing correct output. I tried all the combination like `Qt::ElideLeft` , `Qt::ElideRight`, `Qt::ElideNone`  in above code.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile I tried to print the elided string, which is correct.  But in table it is not showing correct string. For `Qt::ElideLeft` and `Qt::ElideNone` it is showing ... ... ( 6 dots ) in the Name field but not the correct string.

Comment: Well, then you need to post the code to a different question and prepare a minimal reproducible example so that other people can have a look at it.